# Fazer galeria de anime e manga em c# desktop

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados

Para você ler um manga online, você tem que entrar em alguns sites como "MangasProject" para ver o que foi lançado e visualizar o manga para ler.

Quero fazer uma galeria de animes para armazenar fotos e descrição de anime e manga para os usuários, lista de anos que foi lançado, lista de categoria, "Ação,comédia".

A duvida é, como fazer esse projeto? não sei se faço em Asp.net ou C# usando Webform.

Segue foto do ilustrativa de como eu estava fazendo em C# usando WindowsForm 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que possa ser feito em Windows Forms ou então [em XAML](http://www.wpftutorial.net/XAML.html). O XAML é até mais adequado por já estar pronto para outras tecnologias Microsoft, como Tablets e Telefones.

Não faria em ASP.NET até porque o seu intuito é um projeto Desktop, e não um projeto Web.